# MySQL Workbench > Plugins > Utilities > Reformat SQL Query

Tags: mysql, plugins, workbench, utilities, reformatting

At some point I installed MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 Revision 10398.
This version has the feature to reformat an SQL query located at:

**Plugins** > **Utilities** > **Reformat SQL Query**

I like this feature and I use it almost every day.

Now every newer version I downloaded from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ misses this feature.

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 99):

Just answering my own question. I found the feature by accident. It was moved and renamed to and is now located here:

**Edit** > **Format** > **Beautify Query**

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: Just want to add that this function will not work if statement is invalid.

Comment: You can also mark your answer as correct ... that way others can quickly see, that this questions has a correct answer

Comment: Is there a way to configure the Beautify to keep comments?

Answer (score -1):

Now there is a simple icon (looks like a brush) Just click it and wa-la... your ugly SQL is now a work of art. Take a screenshot of it and sell it as a NFT on opensea.io :)