# Is it possible to auto-indent a query in mysql-worckbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, auto-indent

I mean, something equivalent to simple formatting plugin that automatically indents code.  Is there something in this sense?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938297/mysql-workbench-plugins-utilities-reformat-sql-query

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-main-menu.html) you will have **Beautify Query** option

select the query you want to format in editor and then do

```
Edit -> format -> Beautify Query
```

Comment: Short-cut: `Ctrl + B`

Comment: Tried Ctrl + B in windows/workbench. Didnot work for me.

Comment: I am using Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04. This option seems like it has formatted something when clicked. But nothing changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

This Works:

```
Edit -> format -> Beautify Query
```

NOTE: You have to click it always, it does not happen on saving the Query.

Shortcut: `Ctrl + B`

Answer (score 0):

Following options are available:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
2. Edit -> format -> Beautify Query